# Why are these matching unions non-equivalent in Flow?

Tags: flowtype

[Link to Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwCYCUoEcCuUDOIYC8MA3gD4wD6F40AdggLZQBcMA5IqhtnmzKQF8YoSLABiAewBOAIwCWSJFFqES5KjWWMW7SbIVLafQcBHQYAUTkgAFlCkB5GQCsoAY3xFOaLLnzk9eUVlM1grW3sAGWt7BAAbVQAib24-RP4YRMCDZUTTNwlaPBgoazspaJBYuNZw8srqpJTfPDzgAqL8UojHF3cQWrL7J1cPVWINUXomVm76mKl4gSA)

From this test it looks like Flow can only check union equivalence at the top-level. I would like to know way to fix this error, preferably without a switch statement with every case of the union accounted for.

```
type BadRequest = {| __typename: 'BadRequest' |} 
type Forbidden = {| __typename: 'Forbidden' |}

type EitherObject = BadRequest | Forbidden
type EitherLiteral = "BadRequest" | "Forbidden"

const eitherLiteral: EitherLiteral = "BadRequest"

const eitherObject: EitherObject = {__typename: eitherLiteral} // Error?
```

Comment: I *think* Flow considers `__typename` in `BadRequest` and `__typename` in `Forbidden` to be two different properties.

What is your end goal here? I think you just have to use a union type on `__typename` but it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ricola Thank you. var `eitherLiteral` is dynamic and needs to be assigned to 
var `eitherObject`'s `__typename`. This is a simplified example.

To me it seems Flow cannot detect union intersections on nested keys. It feels like an oversight unless there is some Flow syntax to make this work?

Comment: ***I think you just have to use a union type on __typename but it depends what you are trying to do***
The union type `eitherObject` is auto-generated by a plugin and cannot easily be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the answer you wanted to read, but if you have no control on the `EitherObject` type definition then you will need some conversion to keep it type safe:

```
function eitherObjectFromEitherLiteral(eitherLiteral: EitherLiteral) : EitherObject {
    switch(eitherLiteral){
        case 'BadRequest': 
          return { __typename: 'BadRequest'};
        default:
          (eitherLiteral: 'Forbidden')
          return {__typename: 'Forbidden'};
          
    }
}
```

[Flow Try Link](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAQgQwCYCUoEcCuUDOIYC8MA3gD4wD6F40AdggLZQBcMA5IqhtnmzKQF8YoSLABiAewBOAIwCWSJFFqES5KjWWMW7SbIVLafQcBHQYAUTkgAFlCkB5GQCsoAY3xFOaLLnzk9eUVlM1grW3sAGWt7BAAbVQAib24-RP4YRMCDZUTTNwlaPBgoazspaJBYuNZw8srqpJTfPDzgADNMWg85QpKy+ydXDzEpCQY6qJipeIAKUoiK6fjagaWqmbiAShhVxaH3fGJgGFOYHAB3azcbebWGza3js5eYNwQcWA5kHx4QNlYJ1eLykUBAmCkKmIlGoonoTFY3y4LX+AgA3EDgUp2ghMHEQMxMcCYHdFg8VrppEFDGwtkTgaDwZCSBo4dpEdlgkZ0fTXkSBMABEA)